# How to use oAuth2 with nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js

I have successfully created a token and can log in against my oAuth2 service (but only in postman)

now I want to implement this also in my nuxt.js / Vue application.

Which is the way you would prefer to embed the oAuth2 standard (refresh token, etc., etc.) when I use Nuxt.js / vue.js?

thx

Edit: I will give this a try :p
https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/oauth2